# Azure Function HttpTrigger returns 500, if function runs longer then 5 seconds. Why?

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-functions

I run a HttpTrigger Azure Function which runs above 5 seconds. Locally it works like a charm but deployed it returns "(500) Internal Server Error".

EDIT: It only happens if I deploy it to a FunctionApp with Private Endpoints enabled.

Steps to reproduce (fails):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTest.TestFunction
{
    public class TestFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
           
            log.LogInformation("Before sleep");
            Thread.Sleep(7000);
            log.LogInformation("After sleep");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce (works):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTest.TestFunction
{
    public class TestFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
           
            log.LogInformation("Before sleep");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            log.LogInformation("After sleep");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

My host.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
  "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:15:00",
}
```

FYI: The non-test function does not use sleep but just takes longer then 5 seconds.

Comment: is this sample also throwing a 500 error?

Comment: Yes exactly, the one with 7000 ms timeout.

Comment: Set "functionTimeout": "00:10:00" worked for me as I described in the below answer. @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

The `500` error is not helpful to solve this problem, you need to check the specific error of the azure function. You can use **Application Insights** to get more details. The function must configure the corresponding application insights before you can view the log on the portal.

Also, try to add the extension bundle property to your `host.json` file, like so:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
  "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:15:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately I only get data in Application Insights if I use  a 2000ms timeout. If I use the 5000ms timeout I can not even see this call in the Application Insights. The Logs from the Kudu Console look good in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

***I've created an Azure Httptrigger Function in local and ran successfully as shown below:***

[image]

***I deployed it to the Azure portal and got the following error:***

[image]

As per above error, I made changes in `host.json` file as ***"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionTimeout must be greater than 00.00.01 and less than 00.10.00"*** :

***host.json:***

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
       }
    }
},
"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

*After making changes in `host.json` only, I deployed it to Azure again and received **200 OK** response by setting*:

***Thread.Sleep(7000);***

[image]

***Thread.Sleep(2000);***

[image]

Comment: For me I still receive the 500 error when calling over powershell. But I can not see my function in Code + Test.

Comment: You mean in local or after deployment to Azure? Which runtime stack version you are using!

Comment: After deployment. But the reason that it doesn't work seems to be related to private endpoints. I have deployed it to a function app without private endpoints and there even above 5000ms timeout it works.

Comment: I've used .NET6 LTS version and ran as per your concern. I've deployed the same to Azure without any private endpoints. It worked for me. Did you change config in host.json file?

Comment: Yes without private endpoints it works. But not with private endpoints.

Comment: Do you want to run with or without private endpoints?

Comment: I want to run with private endpoints